# My display:flex does not wrap my content properly

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm doing my assignment and I have a tough time figuring out why my content doesn't wrap properly in my box. I checked the parent content area, it uses percentages instead of pixels and doesn't take up more than the screen area.
I've added the code for both the html and css.

```css
#popularLocationsCapsule {
  width: 90%;
  margin-left: 5%;
  display: flex;
}

.popularTemplate {
  width: 50%;
  margin: 5px;
  min-width: 400px;
  max-width: 600px;
}

.popularTemplateMain {
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
}

.popularTemplateMain img {
  width: 65%;
  height: 65%;
  margin: 2px;
}

.popularTemplateDetails {
  width: 40%;
  text-align: center;
}

.popularTemplateDetails p {
  background: #F7882F;
  height: 12.3%;
  padding-top: 5.5%;
  padding-bottom: 7%;
  margin: 1%;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div id="popularLocationsCapsule">

  <section class="popularTemplate">
    <section class="popularTemplateMain">
      <img src="images/london.jpg" />
      <section class="popularTemplateDetails">
        <p>London, GB </p>
        <p>23 October</p>
        <p>7 nights</p>
        <p>23 kgs Luggage</p>
      </section>
    </section>
  </section>

  <section class="popularTemplate">
    <section class="popularTemplateMain">
      <img src="images/tokyo.jpg" />
      <section class="popularTemplateDetails">
        <p>Tokyo, JPN </p>
        <p>6 August</p>
        <p>13 nights</p>
        <p>21 kgs Luggage</p>
      </section>
    </section>
  </section>

  <section class="popularTemplate">
    <section class="popularTemplateMain">
      <img src="images/gravityfalls.jpg" />
      <section class="popularTemplateDetails">
        <p>Gravity Falls </p>
        <p>18 June</p>
        <p>6.18 Nights</p>
        <p>618 kgs Luggage</p>
      </section>
    </section>
  </section>
</div>
```

[image: Fullscreen 1600 x 900]

[image: Smaller]

Comment: You need to add `flex-wrap: wrap;` to your flex container, for example to `#popularLocationsCapsule` if you want your elements to be wraped inside that, if I corretly understood your question

Comment: The thing is I forgot to mention I tried adding it, but then it just put them one below the other. I played around with it and coulnd't get it to work. For some reason I tried it again and now it works ... Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is 2 things you need to do:

- Add `flex-wrap: wrap;` to the `#popularLocationsCapsule`
- Change your set with on `.popularTemplate` to `width: calc(50% - 10px);`

For a flex item to be able to wrap, it needs to be allowed, and `flex-wrap: wrap` fix that, and then, as you both had a width of 50% + a margin of 5px (on each side), there won't fit more than 1, so by subtracting the margin from the width, using [CSS Calc()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc), there will now fit 2 items.

Stack snippet

```css
#popularLocationsCapsule {
  width: 90%;
  margin-left: 5%;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;                      /*  added  */
}

.popularTemplate {
  width: calc(50% - 10px);              /*  changed  */
  margin: 5px;
  min-width: 400px;
  max-width: 600px;
}

.popularTemplateMain {
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
}

.popularTemplateMain img {
  width: 65%;
  height: 65%;
  margin: 2px;
}

.popularTemplateDetails {
  width: 40%;
  text-align: center;
}

.popularTemplateDetails p {
  background: #F7882F;
  height: 12.3%;
  padding-top: 5.5%;
  padding-bottom: 7%;
  margin: 1%;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div id="popularLocationsCapsule">

  <section class="popularTemplate">
    <section class="popularTemplateMain">
      <img src="images/london.jpg" />
      <section class="popularTemplateDetails">
        <p>London, GB </p>
        <p>23 October</p>
        <p>7 nights</p>
        <p>23 kgs Luggage</p>
      </section>
    </section>
  </section>

  <section class="popularTemplate">
    <section class="popularTemplateMain">
      <img src="images/tokyo.jpg" />
      <section class="popularTemplateDetails">
        <p>Tokyo, JPN </p>
        <p>6 August</p>
        <p>13 nights</p>
        <p>21 kgs Luggage</p>
      </section>
    </section>
  </section>

  <section class="popularTemplate">
    <section class="popularTemplateMain">
      <img src="images/gravityfalls.jpg" />
      <section class="popularTemplateDetails">
        <p>Gravity Falls </p>
        <p>18 June</p>
        <p>6.18 Nights</p>
        <p>618 kgs Luggage</p>
      </section>
    </section>
  </section>
</div>
```